# No data displays the run console of Talend Open Studio

Tags: talend

I want just display the content of my table from oracle database in the run console. I have used **tLogRow** but when I execute the job no data displays in the console.

Here is what is displayed in the console:

```
[statistics] connecting to socket on port 4080
[statistics] connected
[statistics] disconnected
Job job_test ended 07/13/2016 at 15:34. [Exit code = 0]
```

You can see what I've done:
[image: You can see what I've done]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure about your query and your schema ? We could use a look on both.

If you just want to display the content, try to drag & drop your table "Facture" directly from metadata on the main view, to get it as a tOracleInput component, this will instantly create a "select * from " query.
*(it seems that it's not what you did, as the tOracleInput in the screenshot would have been renamed "FACTURE")*

Comment: I have testing another table and it works (data is displayed in the run console). But for this table "FACTURE" not!

Comment: It works :) thanks for your help ! it was a trivial problem! data was not correctly inserted in the table FACTURE.